# sbt testOnly runs multiple tests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, sbt

When I run:

```
sbt testOnly com.blablabla.A
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
[error] Failed: Total 19, Failed 6, Errors 0, Passed 13, Ignored 6
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         com.blablabla.A
[error]         com.blablabla.B
[error]         com.blablabla.C
[error] (test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Jul 1, 2020 12:35:08 PM
```

Why?

I only want to test A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason

```
sbt testOnly com.blablabla.A
```

does not work is because here sbt runs in [batch mode](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running.html#Batch+mode) which means it considers each *space-separated* value as a separate command and tries to execute them in sequence. For example, it considers `testOnly` as one command, and then `com.blablabla.A` as the next command

```
sbt    testOnly      com.blablabla.A
          |                  |
      1st command      2nd command
```

The solution is to enclose commands that take arguments themselves in quotes

```
sbt    clean        compile     "testOnly       TestA TestB"
         |            |             |                |
    1st command   2nd command    3rd command    args to 3rd command
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
sbt "testOnly com.blablabla.A"
```

Comment: Splitting this into two commands (ie `sbt` (go into SBT console) and `testOnly com.blablabla.A` (run this test)) also works.